# Convert order total to default currency in Halk Bank Payment Gateway For Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders

I'm using custom bank gateway that accept only "Macedonian denar" "MKD" - currency.

Because I'm using 3 more currencies in WooCommerce, i'm using this code:

```
add_filter( 'halk_amount_fix', function( $total ) { return $total * 62; } );
```

EUR currency and every other currency are converted (multiplied) * 62 after I "Place Order"

For example:

- I want to donate 50 EUR: http://prntscr.com/1381r46
- My gateway accept only MKD (Macedonian denar)
- On the gateway page the total amount is: 50 * 62= 3100 MKD , which is okey for EUR currency

But if the currency on the order page is USD $, the exchange rate for USD/MKD is * 50 , using the above code, 50 USD are converted same as EUR.

---

How can i upgrade the function/filter to get the currency first from the order object? like:

- If it is USD to use * 50 rate
- If it is EUR to use * 62 rate
- If it is GBP to use * 45 rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*How can i upgrade the function/filter to get the currency first from the order object?*"

It seems that the plugin you are using has not received any updates for quite some time. So asking the plugin developers to provide this does not immediately seem like an option.

The solution I am writing here is one that is normally strongly discouraged, because the changes will be lost if the plugin receives an update, but this seems unlikely.

So to answer your question

In `woo-halkbank-payment-gateway/classes/class-wc-halk-payment-gateway.php`

Replace (line 302)

```php
$amount = number_format( apply_filters( 'halk_amount_fix', $order->get_total() ),  2, '.', '' );  //Transaction amount
```

With

```php
$amount = apply_filters( 'halk_amount_fix', number_format( $order->get_total(),  2, '.', ''), $order );  //Transaction amount
```

And then you can apply the following code, via the `halk_amount_fix` filter hook

```php
function filter_halk_amount_fix( $amount, $order ) {            
    // Get currency
    $currency_code = $order->get_currency();
        
    // Compare
    if ( $currency_code == 'USD' ) {
        return number_format( $amount * 50, 2, '.', '' );
    } elseif ( $currency_code == 'EUR' ) {
        return number_format( $amount * 62, 2, '.', '' );
    } elseif ( $currency_code == 'GBP' ) {
        return number_format( $amount * 45, 2, '.', '' );
    }
    
    return $amount;
}
add_filter( 'halk_amount_fix', 'filter_halk_amount_fix', 10, 2 );
```

---

Another option is to directly specify all the code in the file, so that the hook is no longer applicable.